# Trying to precompile assets on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, asset-pipeline, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
2013-11-03 20:30:48,342 [INFO] (30173 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: /usr/bin/ruby1.9 /usr/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (): [/usr/bin/ruby1.9 /usr/bin/rake assets:prec...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Rake task failed to run, skipping asset compilation.
```

How do I precompile assets on AWS Elastic Beanstalk ?

I am getting following error

Answer (score 3):

Precompilation of assets can be done at deployment time, and to do it, go to the root of your Rails project and create a `.ebextensions` directory with a `.config` file in it. You can specify precompilation there. I'm running a Rails app with Elastic Beanstalk and had problems with fonts not being shown. Here's my `.ebextensions/ruby.config` file:

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []

container_commands:
  01_assets:
    command: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
    leader_only: true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customise the system by running scripts before or after your application deployment.
Basically, you need to create a `.ebextensions` directory in your source code and insert your commands and customisation steps in a YAML syntax.
The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_custom_container.html) explains the details.

Beware that these commands are run as 'root' with no environment variable setup.  If you need variables like `PATH` or other, it is up to you to position them.

Here is a sample I wrote for an application which required a NodeJS module installation from the source.

```
packages:
   yum:
      gcc: []
      gcc-c++: []


container_commands:

   10_pre_install_sqlite3:
      command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v0.10.21-linux-x64/bin/npm install sqlite3@2.1.16 --build-from-source"
      cwd: "/tmp/deployment/application"
      env:
          HOME: "/root"
          PATH: "/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin"
```